# Why is my singly linked list not being assigned values properly?

Tags: java

I am doing the LeetCode challenge 'Add Two Numbers'

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.

> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

I was writing a solution, but observed some strange behavior which I am not able to comprehend. (I think the issue is in my for loop).

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */

class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        
        l1= reverseList(l1);
        l2= reverseList(l2);
        
        String str1 = returnListAsString(l1);
        String str2 = returnListAsString(l2);
        
        Integer int1 = Integer.valueOf(str1.toString());
        Integer int2 = Integer.valueOf(str2.toString());
        Integer sum = int1 + int2;
        
        System.out.println("sum.." + sum);
        
        char[] ch = String.valueOf(sum).toCharArray();
        
        
        ListNode result = l1;
        for (int i=0; i<ch.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("test.." + ch[i]);
            result.val = ch[i];
            System.out.println("test2.."+ result.val);
            result = result.next;
        }
        
        return result;
    }
    
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode l1) {
        ListNode previous = null;
        ListNode curr = l1;
        ListNode next = null;
        while (curr != null) {
            next = curr.next;
            curr.next = previous;
            previous = curr;
            curr = next;
        }
        l1 = previous;
        return l1;
    }
    
    public String returnListAsString(ListNode l1) {
        StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
        while (l1 !=null) {
            str1.append(l1.val);
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        
        return str1.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my input

> [2,4,3]
> [5,6,4]

stdout

> sum..807
> test..8
> test2..56
> test..0
> test2..48
> test..7
> test2..55

output

> []

I think the issue is inside my for loop. My question is, why does test and test2 not equal, and how can I have an output that at least says [8,0,7]?

Comment: I think you were supposed to implement long addition.

Comment: The addition works fine because it correctly gives me 807 as the sum. I just need to convert this to a singly linked list (and then I can reverse the list); my problem is that there definition of a linked list is not working for me and is not testable; I'm not even sure how to create a linked list using there definition of it.

Comment: I would check what exactly is being returned.... Hint: calling the iterating variable `result` can be misleading. Also not sure if re-using the input list is such a good idea, what if the result is *longer*? BTW there is no need for first reversing, StringBuilder can also insert characters at the first position

Comment: I don't think you need to reverse to the list.  You create a sum list and int carry variable to store carry over.  You iterate over the both input lists and add the value of the two nodes and the carry over value to the sum list.  Do this until one of the list is empty.  Then append the rest of the values from the longer list to the sum list.

Comment: I appreciate the responses and I realize my solution isn't optimal, but my original question is why the test and test2 values being returned in stdout are not equal? For example, where is it getting the value '56'?

Comment: The constraints of the LeetCode problem state that each linked list may contain up to 100 nodes. That means a number with 100 digits. A number that size is larger than [Integer.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE). You may be able to create a [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) for it. Basically, I don't think your solution is feasible. The fact that the digits are in reverse order is meant to help you with the solution and not to force you to reverse the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think the issue is inside my for loop

Definitely. You set `result` to `l1`. Then you assign `result` to `result.next`. Eventually you assign null to `result`. Hence your "empty" output. The first element in the `char` array, i.e. `ch` needs to become the last `ListNode`. The second element in `ch` needs to become the second last `ListNode`.

Here is my rewrite of your code:

```java
public class Solution {

    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        l1 = reverseList(l1);
        l2 = reverseList(l2);
        String str1 = returnListAsString(l1);
        String str2 = returnListAsString(l2);
        Integer int1 = Integer.valueOf(str1.toString());
        Integer int2 = Integer.valueOf(str2.toString());
        Integer sum = int1 + int2;
        System.out.println("sum.." + sum);
        char[] ch = String.valueOf(sum).toCharArray();
        ListNode result = null;
        ListNode temp = new ListNode(ch[0] - '0');
        for (int i = 1; i < ch.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("test.." + ch[i]);
            result = new ListNode(ch[i] - '0', temp);
            temp = result;
            System.out.println("test2.." + result.val);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode l1) {
        ListNode previous = null;
        ListNode curr = l1;
        ListNode next = null;
        while (curr != null) {
            next = curr.next;
            curr.next = previous;
            previous = curr;
            curr = next;
        }
        l1 = previous;
        return l1;
    }

    public String returnListAsString(ListNode l1) {
        StringBuilder str1 = new StringBuilder();
        while (l1 != null) {
            str1.append(l1.val);
            l1 = l1.next;
        }
        return str1.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ListNode three = new ListNode(3);
        ListNode four = new ListNode(4, three);
        ListNode two = new ListNode(2, four);
        ListNode fore = new ListNode(4);
        ListNode six = new ListNode(6, fore);
        ListNode five = new ListNode(5, six);
        Solution soln = new Solution();
        ListNode rslt = soln.addTwoNumbers(two, five);
        System.out.println("Result: " + soln.returnListAsString(rslt));
    }
}

class ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode next;

    ListNode() {
        this(0);
    }

    ListNode(int val) {
        this(val, null);
    }

    ListNode(int val, ListNode next) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

Output when running the above code:

```
sum..807
test..0
test2..0
test..7
test2..7
Result: 708
```

> I appreciate the responses and I realize my solution isn't optimal, but my original question is why the test and test2 values being returned in stdout are not equal?

I believe I have answered your question.

### Edit

Here is the solution I submitted to *LeetCode* which was accepted.

```
public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    ListNode lst = null;
    ListNode res = null;
    ListNode tmp = null;
    int carry = 0;
    int sum;
    while (l1 != null) {
        sum = l1.val;
        if (l2 != null) {
            sum += l2.val;
            l2 = l2.next;
        }
        sum += carry;
        carry = sum > 9 ? 1 : 0;
        if (carry > 0) {
            sum %= 10;
        }
        tmp = new ListNode(sum);
        if (res == null) {
            res = tmp;
            lst = tmp;
        }
        else {
            lst.next = tmp;
            lst = tmp;
        }
        l1 = l1.next;
    }
    while (l2 != null) {
        sum = l2.val + carry;
        carry = sum > 9 ? 1 : 0;
        if (carry > 0) {
            sum %= 10;
        }
        tmp = new ListNode(sum);
        if (res == null) {
            res = tmp;
            lst = tmp;
        }
        else {
            lst.next = tmp;
            lst = tmp;
        }
        l2 = l2.next;
    }
    if (carry == 1) {
        tmp = new ListNode(carry);
        lst.next = tmp;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output for "test" prints a String representation of a character, your "test2" output prints the integer value of that character. The integer value of `'0'` is 48 (ASCII or UTF8-encoding).

You would have to parse back the `char` value to the proper `int`:

```
result.val = Integer.parseInt("" + ch[i]);
```

Still a very complicated solution, and if @Abra is right, I would suggest that you don't convert the numbers to any object first, but add them digit by digit and keep the overflow (anything that is bigger than 9) for the next digit.

You still have to take care, when both numbers do not have the same length and that the overflow of the last digit of input is appended to the output.

This method would also save you from reversing the result again, it's output from the lowest significant value to the highest.